# Insufficient permissions when calling the AddLFTagsToResource (AWS LakeFormation)

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark

I have been trying to set up an Upsert job in AWS Glue, which uses pyspark to create and update tables at the data lake catalog database (in Lakeformation). This job also applied LFTags to the resources (tables and columns).
The error I keep receiving is always about Insufficient Permissions.
E.g.:

```js
022-01-18 21:11:58,381 ERROR [main] glue.ProcessLauncher (Logging.scala:logError(73)): Error from Python:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/driver.py", line 186, in <module>
    run()
  File "/tmp/driver.py", line 182, in run
    main(sys.argv)
  File "/tmp/driver.py", line 173, in main
    cf.process_spark(spark)
  File "/tmp/spark_pyutil-0.0.1-py3-none-any.zip/spark_pyutil/conf_process.py", line 772, in process_spark
    self.__write_output_spark(spark, df_udf)
  File "/tmp/spark_pyutil-0.0.1-py3-none-any.zip/spark_pyutil/conf_process.py", line 543, in __write_output_spark
    r = lk.add_lf_tags_to_resource(Resource=table_resource, LFTags = lf_tags)
  File "/home/spark/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 386, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/home/spark/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 705, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.errorfactory.AccessDeniedException: An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the AddLFTagsToResource operation: Insufficient Glue permissions to access table gene_genesymbol
```

I also tried unchecking the options

```
> Use only IAM access control for new databases Use only IAM access
> control for new tables in new databases
```

And add Associate and Describe permissions to the role in all LFTags in Lakeformation.

In another scenario, I tried adding different policies to the IAM role, checking theIAM access control options, and it also results in Insufficient permissions.

Does anybody see something off in what I'm doing?

Answer (score 0):

Pretty late response but hopefully it may help someone else. I found that I needed to add the IAM Role to Data lake administrators as well. I think the logic is that in order to add the LF Tag to the Resource, the IAM Role first needs to be able to access that Resource. Adding it to Data lake administrators is one way. A more fine-grained way would be to grant permissions on that specific Resource.